# Superset database connection with Teradata error

Tags: kubernetes, teradata, apache-superset

I am trying to connect TD with superset running in kube. This is code from my Dockerfile:

```
USER root
    RUN pip install sqlalchemy-teradata
    RUN pip install teradatasql
    RUN pip install "apache-superset[teradata]"
    COPY tdodbc1700 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/
    ENV ODBCINI=/.../teradata/client/ODBC_64/odbc.ini
ENV ODBCINST=/.../teradata/client/ODBC_64/odbcinst.ini
```

This is the sql alchemy URI I am giving:

teradata://user:pwd@host:port/schema

Error I am getting:

"Unexpected error occurred, please check your logs for details"

I am not sure where to check log for more details? Please suggest how to get TD connected with Superset.

Note:

1. tdodbc1700 used in Dockerfile is ODBC driver for Linux. This is unzipped folder downloaded from TD site.
2. The base image I am using is amancevice/superset:latest

Comment: Why not use the `teradatasqlalchemy` package (dialect `teradatasql:` from package `teradatasql`) and avoid ODBC completely. If you do need to use `sqlalchemy-teradata` and `teradata` plus ODBC for some reason, then you need to at least include the client library (e.g. `.../teradata/client/17.00/lib64`)  in your LIBPATH and append option `driver="Teradata Database ODBC Driver 17.00"` to your connection string.

Comment: Thanks. It did work. I am able to see the schema and tables are getting listed in SQLLAB and Database section. But when I am trying to query or preview, getting error: "DB engine Error
[Version 17.0.0.8] [Session 140501483] [Teradata Database] [Error 3535] A character string failed conversion to a numeric value.  at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).formatDatabaseError TeradataConnection.go:1139 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).makeChainedDatabaseError TeradataConnection.go:1155 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).

"

Comment: If you are passing a character string that represents a date value, it generally should be in `YYYY-MM-DD` form. That's the most common, non-obvious reason for 3535 error. If that's not the issue, you probably would need to look at the SQL being sent to the database (e.g. use DBQL to log the text on the Teradata side) to understand what is wrong.